# Como pasar valores de un PHP a otro PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo un codigo en html-PHP que es el siguiente

```
<form action="index2.php?idubicacion=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" method="GET" >
    <select>
        <?php
            include("conexion.php");

            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbubicaciones";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
            while($row = $resultado ->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" /><?php echo $row['Ubicacion']; ?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="Aceptar" >

</form>
```

donde muestro en un list ciertas ubicaciones y agarran de valor un ID, ejemplo:

ID  | Ubicaciones

1   |  SALA

2 | COCINA

Lo que busco es mandar por URL el valor de ID y recogerlo en otro PHP  pero no lo consigo: lo unico que se manda es:
index2.php?Aceptar=Enviar

agradeceria su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué menor no unes ambos PHP con include o require?

Comment: Al principio de la pagina el usuario necesita hacer una selección de ubicación y necesito recoger ese parametro (ID) para trabajarlo en mas paginas que se van a desarrollar

Comment: en la otra vista puedes utilizar `$_GET['ID']`

Comment: Entonces considera usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Supongo que el dato de la ubicación lo seleccionará cada usuario desde su interfaz cliente.

Comment: Tu problema es que el `select` no tiene el atributo `name`, entonces no hay variable para transportar la información, [aprender a usar select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). Otra cosa que no entiendo bien es por qué en la primera línea hay un `echo $row['ID']`, pero más adelante hay `while($row = $resultado ->fetch_assoc())`. ¿La variable `$row` está definida antes de llegar al `while`? ¿Y si es así, por qué la reescribes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes recibir el valor del select desde index2.php, lo que tienes que hacer es agregar un nombre al select para poder leer el valor de la variable, ej:

```
<select name="ubicacion">
```

Luego en index2.php lo encuentras como `$_GET['ubicacion']`

Puedes sacar la variable del get del Form, dejaría solo `<form action="index2.php" method="GET">`.
En realidad yo preferiría pasar todo con el método POST, es más seguro si en index2.php vas a realizar algun CRUD.

Comment: Tienes razon, me faltaba agregarle un nombre al select, se lo agrege y sin problemas pude pasar el parametro y es correcto, despues del index2.php voy a realizar algun CRUD pero ya lo pasaria con POST, gracias.